# indexing data arrays in reverse manner (newest data get the last no. since my data are arranged from newest to oldest which means from last to first)

Tags: javascript

I have indexed my array(posts) through the code below. The problem is that I need to index them in a reverse manner (from larger to lower) since my data is displayed from the newest to oldest  so I want the newest post get the last index no. in the array which now is the opposite(newest get no 0). Also, how can I start indexing from no. 1 not 0 any ideas?

```
  this.posts.forEach((post, index) => {post.index = index})
```

Comment: Getting confused, Is `posts` is an array of primitive values or an `array of objects` ? If it's an array of objects, You want to add an `index` property in each object ?

Comment: its array of objects and the code above adds index to each object but the problem I'm getting the data from server so the data I get is arranged from newest to oldest and the index value for the newest post is 0 but I want it to be the opposite

Comment: The data you get is already sorted, you just need to simply traverse the array and set the properties

Comment: I'm not sure about your data format, but looking at your code, try `this.posts.forEach((post, index) => {post.index = this.posts.length - index - 1})`

Comment: @Ian OP says start index at 1, so I think `this.posts.forEach((post, index) => {post.index = this.posts.length - index})`. Given an array with 3 elements, the first iteration, length is 3, and `forEach` index is 0. First iteration, 3 - 0 = **3**. Second iteration, 3 - 1 = **2**, third iteration 3 - 2 = **1**. Done. `[3,2,1]`.

Comment: Yes, actually my comment didn't have -1 at first, but then I saw the OP's comment "`The latest post is 0, but I want it to be the other way around `" so I adjusted it to -1 again, but Whether result want -1 or not, I believe OP can handle it according to his own logic after seeing it

Comment: thanks Ian and @bloodyKunuckles this solved my problem completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now what I understood as per the above comments, You want to index the newest post with last index and oldest with the first index. If Yes, You can do this by using [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) **:**

```js
const posts = ['newest', 'old', 'oldest'];

const res = posts.map((post, index) => {
    return {
    name: post,
    index: posts.length - index
  }
});

console.log(posts); // original array without mutate
console.log(res); // New array of objects with index properties
```

Comment: thanks this seems to fix it too but I already fixed it with the above comments thanks for your efforts too